# Non readable menu items in many apps like gimp, shutter

Tags: 17.10, gui, gimp

I am using Ubuntu 17.10 and some apps have menu items invisible, white on white like on the screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

Does anyhone know how to fix it?

Comment: Which apps exactly are not working? Gimp has a bit specific interface. It'd also be helpful if you could share which environment (GNOME, Unity, KDE ... ?) are you using.

Comment: Did you change themes, fonts, etc or is this a completely out-of-the-box desktop?

Comment: @Zlatan In past I was switching between KDE and Unity on the same install.  Then finally settled on current default Ubuntu gnome shell (unity replacement) in 17.10 (through the upgrade). Shutter was another one. I am upgrading to 18.04 to see if that helps.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I do not think I have changed any themes, should be default ubuntu install (with few release upgrades). I actually have the same problem on two of my PCs.

Comment: And the problem appeared after you switched to Gnome on 17.10?

Comment: I use LXDE desktop on top of Ubuntu, this happened to me with the default Ubuntu theme (maybe Adwaita - not sure). I installed Lubuntu-default theme and it fixed it.  Suggest trying another theme, it's easy and reversible.

Comment: @Zlatan I think so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it by removing .gtkrc-2.0. All apps (gimp, inkscape) instantly restored their default styles.

```
rm -rf ~/.gtkrc-2.0
```